# Normal internet doesn't work

Tags: help

I've installed tor yesterday and it's been working ok. But I noticed today that chrome, skype and spotify work. I can only connect to the internet through tor. Is this tor's fault or totally unrelated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tor doesn't affect anything outside of itself, it doesn't reconfigure your OS or applications.

Answer (score 1):

Tor is a standalone app by itself - it does not change a single network settings. To utilize it you are responsible to repatch your routes. So it's your setup that is needed to be corrected. If you'll add some details of what your OS is and what exactly you have done and what do you want to achieve - we'll be able to help you further